# Laptop display misaligned / incorrect scaling / display bounds

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, bios, display-settings

I have quite a strange issue with my laptop where the resolution/alignment/scaling is incorrect when using windows (Win 10) and even during the boot splash screen / UEFI menu. Specs below:

OcUK Gamer W370ST 17.3" LED Full HD Intel Haswell Processor, 1600MHz DDR3, SSD + HDD, NVIDIA GTX 765M 2GB GDDR5 Graphics Card - Windows Laptop - Cosmic Grey

As you can see the boot logo that would normally appear in the middle is out of place:
[image: Splash screen is not centred]

The right and bottom parts of the UEFI menu are missing:
[image: Right and bottom section of UEFI menu are missing]

And the strangest thing, if I switch off UEFI I get the following BIOS menu:
[image: BIOS menu is pretty broken]
The left and middle sections are reversed (requires a mirror to read) and there are black bars, but the right hand-side appears fine.

I have tried re-installing drivers and disabling display adapters without success. If I plug in an external display via HDMI, content on the external display is displayed correctly, but the laptop screen remains broken.

**Edit 04/04/2020**
In the last couple of weeks or so the issue resolved itself. During this time I took the following screen shot.

[image: Device Manager and screen resolution when working]

Unfortunately the next time I restarted my laptop the problem came back.

I compared the working settings with the now broken ones and noticed that the monitor was now detected as `Digital Flat Panel (1024x768 60hz)` and `20148 x 1536` is now the recommended resolution.

Changing the driver back to `Generic PnP Monitor` made no difference, and setting the resolution back to `1920 x 1080` made things worse (Black bar at top of screen that was inaccessible with the mouse.)

Comment: I would not bet much on it, but your BIOS seems a bit ancient. You might want to try to update it. There is a risk involved, make sure you understand that risk and read the BIOS update manual before proceeding. That is assuming you did not do any BIOS updating before. ;-)

Comment: @TheUser1024 - Thanks, thats probably worth a go. I will try and find an updated BIOS. Yeah I haven't modded the bios (or anything else)

Comment: Clevo nor Overclockers are willing/able to provide me with a BIOS update. This problem sorted itself out for a while, but after a Windows update its back to its broken state. Not sure what else there is to do.